# Add To Cart functionality not working - Context API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management, react-state-management, react-context

I am following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmVVkpCBWpQ&t=89s) and followed it exactly, and I have even gone over github [repo](https://github.com/TommmyKelly/shoping-cart-with-context-api) and code is the same. However when I click my button to add the product to the cart the state does not change. In react dev tools only state that changes is showHideCart changes from false to true - so it seems to only recognise that state change?

I want to be able to add my product to the basket once I click the button - can anyone see where the I have gone wrong? there are no errors in the console and the basket array just does not change it does not even say undefined which was what I thought  would of been the case for no product showing up in basket.

Here is a link to a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/bb120010a5a)

and below is code files where I believe the issues would be:

CartState.js

```
import { useReducer } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from './CartContext'
import {CartReducer} from './CartReducer'
import { SHOW_HIDE_CART, ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from '../Types'

export const CartState = ({children}) => {

    const initialState ={
        showCart: false,
        cartItems: [],

    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, initialState);

    const addToCart = (item) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: item})
    };

    const showHideCart = () => {
        dispatch({type: SHOW_HIDE_CART})
    };

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ITEM, payload: id });
    };


    return (
        <CartContext.Provider 
            value={{
                showCart: state.showCart,
                cartItems: state.cartItems,  
                addToCart,
                showHideCart,
                removeItem,
            }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

CartReducer.js

```
import {ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM, SHOW_HIDE_CART } from '../Types'

export const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SHOW_HIDE_CART: {
            return{
                ...state,
                showCart: !state.showCart
            }
        }
        case ADD_TO_CART: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
            }
        }
        case REMOVE_ITEM: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
            }
        }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { QuantityButtonDiv } from './QuantityButtonDiv'
import {BasketItem} from './BasketItem'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart/CartContext'

export const Product = ({product}) => {

    const {addToCart } = useContext(CartContext)
   

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={product.image}/>
            </div>
            <div className="details-div">
                <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                <span>
                    {product.description}
                </span>
                <span className="price">
                    £ {product.price}
                </span>
                <div className="stock-div">
                    {product.stock} in stock
                </div>
                <QuantityButtonDiv/>
                <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}  className="button">
                    Add To Basket
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

ProductDetailsPAge.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import '../styles/productDetailsPage.scss';
import img from '../assets/image.png'
import { QuantityButtonDiv } from '../components/QuantityButtonDiv';
import { Product } from '../components/Product';

import { CartContext } from '../context/cart/CartContext';




export const ProductDetailsPage = () => {



    const products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Waxed Cotton Hooded Jacket",
            image: require("../assets/image.png"),
            description: "The Drumming jacket in orange is finished with a water-repellent dry wax treatment that creates a love-worn look. It's made in the United Kingdom using organic cotton ripstop with a drawstring hood, underarm eyelets and buttoned flap front pockets. Shoulder epaulettes add a utilitarian twist, while a fly-fronted zip and snap-button closure keeps the overall look streamlined. Attach one of the collection's padded liners to the internal tab on cooler days.",
            price: 650,
            stock: 10,
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div className="product-details-page">
            {
                products.map((product) => (
                    <Product
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    // title={product.title}
                    // image={product.image}
                    // description={item.description}
                    // price={item.price}
                    // stock={item.stock}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where are you use `cartItems`?

Comment: the code looks fine, where are you not getting the updated cart items?

Comment: Im not getting them updated in the state - if you go on the code sandbox and use react dev tools then click add to basket you can see the state of the cart just stays as an empty array [] - does not update

Comment: I have not finished the cart functionality yet to display cartItems as the state does not update so I need to fix this as it is not working

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an error on **basketpage** route

You are passing an **object** through **CartContext**:

```
<CartContext.Provider 
        value={{
            showCart: state.showCart,
            cartItems: state.cartItems,  
            addToCart,
            showHideCart,
            removeItem,
        }}>
```

in **BasketPage** you are destructuring an **array**:

```
    const [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartContext);//Typeerror here
```

Also, you aren't passing neither cart or setCart through that Context value object.

You need to first solve this error and further see if it works alright.

Comment: Apologies ignore that file this is old code I meant to delete that and actually does not work with the current context code I have written - it is not linked up and I do not think affects it

Comment: I am not even displaying anything into my actual frontend basket yet I am literally just trying to get the product to add to my basket state - and seeing this through react dev tools

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with showCart and showHideCart - once I got rid of these the cart was working.